# Number of integer solutions $0 < x < y < z < 25$

Tags: combinatorics

Question 11 from Practice Exam #1 pg. 24 of Counting: The Art of Enumerative Combinatorics by George E. Martin.

How many integer solutions are there to the system 0 < x < y < z < 25 ?

My solutions is count the number of permutations of 3 C's (for choose ) and 21 R's (for reject). Using this technique, I get the following answer:
$$ 
    \frac{24!}{3!21!} = 2024
$$

Is this answer correct?

Comment: Can you post the statement of the question?

Comment: Just to add color - x>=1 and z<=24
So all numbers have to be bound between [1;24]. As x<y<z, the three numbers are distinct and (x;y;z) is a sorted array. Hence the question can also be treated as choosing 3 numbers (without repetition) between 1 and 24 where only one order (ascending) is required. So its 24C3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. Incidentally this is also the number of three element subsets of a set with $24$ elements, also known as $\binom{24}3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your answer is correct. The fact that the no of ways using that is correct because when three numbers are selected randomly from 24 numbers with order not being important ,then  x, y, z gets satisfied. So the thing is 24p3/3!